# In $K[X,Y]$, is the power of any prime also primary?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

I've recently been reading about primary decomposition, and was browsing the questions here.
From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93415/relation-between-primary-ideal-and-prime-ideal), I know that it is *not* true that every primary ideal is the power of a prime ideal.

I'm curious about a slight variation inspired by the comments.

> Consider $K[X,Y]$, for $K$ a field. For any prime $\mathfrak{p}\subset K[X,Y]$, and any $n\geq 1$, is the ideal $\mathfrak{p}^n$ primary, so that if $ab\in\mathfrak{p}^n$, then either $a\in\mathfrak{p}^n$ or $b^j\in\mathfrak{p}^n$ for some $j$?

I suspect it is indeed true, and it is obviously true when $n=1$. An inductive approach doesn't feel right, so is there another way to reach the conclusion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is yes. Recall the following important fact:

**Theorem.** (Reid, *Undergraduate Commutative Algebra*, Proposition page 22) *The prime ideals of $k[x,y]$ are as follows:*

1. $0$;
2. $(f)$, *for irreducible* $f \in k[x,y]$;
3. *maximal ideals* $\mathfrak{m}$.

Now you can easily conclude with the following two facts:
(a) a power of a maximal ideal is primary (Atiyah, Macdonald 4.2); (b) in a UFD the power of a principal prime ideal is primary.

I don't know what happens in general in $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$, when $n \geq 3$. It can be proved that if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a monomial prime in $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ then $\mathfrak{p}^m$ is $\mathfrak{p}$-primary for all $m$.

Comment: I doubt this holds for $n\geq 3$.

Comment: Thanks Andrea. Do you have a proof or reference to a proof of the second fact (b) stated above?

Comment: It is quite easy. Try to prove it on your own.

Comment: @Alex: you are right to doubt! See a non-primary square  of a prime in Atiyah-Macdonald, page 51, Example 3).

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg That doubt refers to the polynomial ring over a field in (at least) three variables. There is such an example in Northcott, *Ideal Theory*, page 29, Example 3.

Comment: dear Andrea, +1, but perhaps it is also worth nothing that point (b) holds in *any* integral domain, not just UFDs :) ... (ie a power of a principal prime ideal in an integral domain is always primary)