# Ring with the property : every power of prime ideal is primary

Tags: commutative-algebra

Is there any special name of ring (commutative ring with unity) with following property : every power of prime ideal is primary ideal? I know that every PID satisfies this property, but what else?

Comment: Certainly Dedekind domains (not surprising, since the property in question is local) and any two dimensional regular ring have this property.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112972/in-kx-y-is-the-power-of-any-prime-also-primary