# Are unique prime ideal factorization domains noetherian?

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noetherian, integral-domain

Let $A$ be a domain satisfying the following condition:

If $\mathfrak p_1,\dots,\mathfrak p_k$ are distinct nonzero prime ideals of $A$, and if $m$ and $n$ are distinct elements of $\mathbb N^k$, then we have 
$$
\mathfrak p_1^{m_1}\cdots\mathfrak p_k^{m_k}\ne\mathfrak p_1^{n_1}\cdots\mathfrak p_k^{n_k}.
$$

> Is $A$ necessarily noetherian?

This question is motivated by these outstanding answers of [user26857](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3056360/660) and [Julian Rosen](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3060152/660).

user26857's answer shows that noetherian domains do satisfy the above condition, whereas Julian's answer shows that many non-noetherian domains do *not* satisfy it.

Comment: It's true for $1$-dimensional valuation domains.  Is it true for valuation domains in general?

Comment: I think there are 1-dimensional valuation domains such that $m^2=m$.

Comment: Yes exactly.  A $1$-dimensional valuation domain is Noetherian iff its max ideal is not idempotent iff it satisfies the property in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call domains having this property $UPIF$-domains, as in your first post.

Observe that a domain which is locally $UPIF$ is $UPIF$.

Indeed, given $$\mathfrak p_1^{m_1}\cdots\mathfrak p_k^{m_k}=\mathfrak p_1^{n_1}\cdots\mathfrak p_k^{n_k}$$
we can localize at each of the $\mathfrak{p_i}$ one at a time and use the assumption that $D_{\mathfrak{p_i}}$ is $UPIF$ to deduce that $m_i = n_i$.

From your linked Questions/Answers, we thus have that a locally Noetherian domain is locally UPIF, hence

> A locally Noetherian domain is $UPIF$.

However, there are locally Noetherian domains that are not Noetherian.

A classic reference for such examples is section 2 of [this paper of Heinzer and Ohm](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1971-158-02/S0002-9947-1971-0280472-2/S0002-9947-1971-0280472-2.pdf).

For a more recent reference, I'd suggest Loper's article on [Almost Dedekind Domains Which Are Not Dedekind](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-0-387-36717-0_17).  In section 3, he discusses five distinct techniques for producing examples of non-Noetherian domains which are locally discrete valuation rings.