# Are unique prime ideal factorization domains locally noetherian?

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noetherian, integral-domain

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3060639/660) I asked: "Are unique prime ideal factorization domains noetherian?".

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3062420/660) Badam Baplan pointed out that *locally* noetherian domains are unique prime ideal factorization domains (UPIFD), that certain non-noetherian domains are locally noetherian (the first example seems to have been given by N. Nakano in 1953), and thus that these non-noetherian domains *are* UPIFD.

This prompts the present question:

> Are unique prime ideal factorization domains *locally* noetherian?

**Edit.** For the sake of completeness recall that a UPIFD is a domain satisfying the following condition:

If $\mathfrak p_1,\dots,\mathfrak p_k$ are distinct nonzero prime ideals of $A$, and if $m$ and $n$ are distinct elements of $\mathbb N^k$, then we have 
$$
\mathfrak p_1^{m_1}\cdots\mathfrak p_k^{m_k}\ne\mathfrak p_1^{n_1}\cdots\mathfrak p_k^{n_k}.
$$

Comment: In my opinion this property is not enough to imply noetherianity, not even locally.

Comment: Crossposted on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/320787/461

Comment: The question has been answered on MathOverflow by Dario Spirito: https://mathoverflow.net/a/321090/461